# Trying to input variable into an already created row in sql database

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to input the score to a quiz into a database in which the user already has an account.

I am getting an error saying - "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error"

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO PlH WHERE username == (?) VALUES (?)",(username,score))
conn.commit()
```

The column names in the sql database are named 'PlH' and 'username' and the variables are 'score' and 'username' respectively

Comment: To change a value of an already created row, use `UPDATE PlH SET score = ? WHERE username = ?`. Don't use `==`, use `=` in SQL. See [SQLite Update](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/).

Comment: To change an existing row use [update](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_update.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you want to refresh the record in the table not to insert a new one. For this purpose you need to use `UPDATE` statement instead. `WHERE` clause of the script will be used to identify the required row (sometimes used for the list of rows updated simultaneously). `SET` clause wil specify the list of fields and new values to be assigned. Read SQLite  documentation for the syntaxis.